# Which is a good editor on Mac that has support for Perforce?

Tags: macos, ide, textmate, perforce, html-editor

1. There is a perforce bundle for TextMate but I can't get to auto-check out a file , when we open a file for edit. Is there a way to do it ?
2. Is there any other thin editor that allows for auto-checkout . ( eclipse is good but too heavy)

Comment: Why was this closed?  The topic is focused (text editor on the Mac platform that has Perforce integration) and it is software development related.  There is AN answer to this question.  That would be a list of editors with Perforce integration.  Perhaps the question could be phrased a bit better, but I just don't understand why questions like this are closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd take a look at vim.  There are a couple of plugins that provide Perforce integration.

Answer (score 1):

It's not free and I haven't actually tried it on Mac, but Slickedit is my favorite multi-platform IDE. It's not lightweight but you wouldn't know from its performance (unlike Eclipse). In windows perforce and Slickedit talk via the standardized SCC interface. Slickedit's the most powerful editor I've used.